# Can't access onActivityResult zxing for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, barcode, zxing, android-fragmentactivity

I'am trying to read the barcode via Zxing in fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_caddie, container, false);
    etCodigo = v.findViewById(R.id.etCodigo);
    btnLeerCodigo = v.findViewById(R.id.btnLeerCodigo);

    btnLeerCodigo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            escanear();
        }
    });
    text = "";

    return v;
}


public void escanear() {

    IntentIntegrator intent = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(FragmentCaddie.this);
    //IntentIntegrator intent = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
    intent.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
    intent.setPrompt("ESCANEAR CODIGO");
    intent.setCameraId(0);
    intent.setBeepEnabled(false);
    intent.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
    intent.initiateScan();

}


 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Cancelaste el escaneo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            text = text + " + " +  result.getContents().toString() ;
            etCodigo.setText(text);
            escanear();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

The issue is it doesn't access the onActivityResult

Comment: What does it mean??? onActivityResult does not return anything?

Comment: @hamidkeyhani it doesn't access this method a used log.d nothing and yes it doesn't return nothing

Comment: Try onActivityResult on your activity and use log.d then report the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quiet simple the `onActivityResult` that i implemented was Overrided from the parent activity

The solution is to call the fragment `onActivityResult` from the parent activity

```
private static final int BARECODE_REQUEST = 114910;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     

    if (requestCode == BARECODE_REQUEST) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The hosting activity overrides `onActivityResult()`, but it did not make a call to `super.onActivityResult()` for unhandled result codes. Apparently, even though the fragment is the one making the `startActivityForResult()` call, the activity gets the first shot at handling the result. This makes sense when you consider the modularity of fragments. Once I implemented `super.onActivityResult()` for all unhandled results, the fragment got a shot at handling the result.

Check this out:

[onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment][1])

I hope to be useful for u :)

Comment: I've combine your solution and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450049/how-get-result-from-onactivityresult-in-fragment Thank You buddy +1

Comment: Happy Coding ;)